# Logarithmic and exponential equation.

Tags: logarithms

Find $x$ in  $$\large3^{\log_{2} {x}} +3^{\log_{x} {2}}=90$$

Comment: Please verify that this expression is copied correctly, as it does not appear to have a nice exact solution as written.

Answer (score 2):

If the expression is correct, then the only thing you can do is notice that

$$\log_x2=\frac{1}{\log_2x}$$

and substitute $y=\log_2x$, which gives

$$3^y+3^{1/y}=90$$

Then you have to use a numerical method to solve for $y$ and finally find $x$ by

$$x=2^y$$